# how do we specify --testdox in phpunit.xml rather than as command line option?

Tags: php, phpunit

The output you get from phpunit when you specify `--testdox` is prettier and more informative than the default dots, so I would like to see it that way all the time. But I've not been able to figure out the way to express my wish for testdox output in a phpunit.xml file, unless it's redirected to a file. I want to see it right away on the console.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's not (yet) possible to configure this in `phpunit.xml`.

Comment: I'd say that qualifies as an Answer :-) Thanks.

Comment: I think you inspired him! I've been looking forward to this for 10+ years and it was done less than 36 hours after you asked this question!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not (yet) possible to configure this in `phpunit.xml`. It should be possible in PHPUnit 8.1.

Comment: It's implemented now: https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/commit/397fd5394260421c67d75b08a1c694f34615faf7

Comment: looks like we are still waiting for zendframework/zend-test to support PHPUnit 8, which is what particularly interests me since I am working with ZF3. so for now I am bash-aliasing my phpunit command.

Comment: Hurray! Thank you so much, @SebastianBergmann! I've been waiting for this feature since the PHPUnit 3 days! I've already implemented it in all of my projects. https://github.com/phpexpertsinc/skeleton/commit/0cacc1f4050363a9f15d9e5ba4b788929e7a3a92

Answer (score 14):

Since PHPUnit 8.1 it is now possible.

You need to do this:

`composer require --dev phpunit/phpunit:'^8.1'`

and then add `testdox="true"` as an attribute of your `<phpunit>` tag.

See my implementation: https://github.com/phpexpertsinc/skeleton/commit/0cacc1f4050363a9f15d9e5ba4b788929e7a3a92

Comment: The correct attribute name is `testdox` as opposed to `textdox`. But yes, this worked on phpunit 8.5

Comment: Fixed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you still have the PHPUnit version lower (<) than 8.1, then add the line below to your `<phpunit ... >` node in your `phpunit.xml`

```
<phpunit
    printerClass="PHPUnit\Util\TestDox\CliTestDoxPrinter"
    ...
</phpunit>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is now possible to [set `testdox` in the `phpunit.xml`](https://docs.phpunit.de/en/10.2/configuration.html#the-testdox-attribute):

```xml
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://schema.phpunit.de/|version|/phpunit.xsd"
         testdox="true"
         >
```